# What are techniques in ASP for communication from usercontrol to parent page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, user-controls, asp.net-ajax

I have having some trouble with communication from a usercontrol to the main page. The order in which events are raised means that the action on the user control occurs too late in the post back to have an effect on the main page.

For example, I have a button on a user control which, when pressed, raises a custom event that is being listened for on the main page. When the button is pressed the postback order is:

> - *page_load* - on the main page
> - *page_load* - on the usercontrol (the user control is loaded programitically by the main page *page_load*)
> - The *button call back* on the user control
> - The *event call back* method on the main page

By this point, it seems it is too late for anything the *event call back* method does to have any effect on the rendered page, for example I am trying to use it to change the usercontrol that is being displayed.

What other techniques can be used for this kind of communication?

Relevant code
Main page:

```
    public string LastLoadedControl
    {
        get
        {
            return Session["LastLoaded"] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            Session["LastLoaded"] = value;
        }
    }

    private void LoadUserControl()
    {
        string controlPath = LastLoadedControl;

        ContentPlaceholder.Controls.Clear();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(controlPath))
            controlPath = Utils.Paths.USERCTRL_BASE + "Main.ascx";

        Control uc = Page.LoadControl(controlPath);
        ContentPlaceholder.Controls.Add(uc);

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadUserControl();
        if (!IsPostBack)
            Utils.Events.redirectPage += Events_redirectPage;

    }

    private void Events_redirectPage(string path)
    {

        if (path.Equals("Main"))
        {
            //Session.Clear();
            //Session.Abandon();
        }
        else LastLoadedControl = Paths.USERCTRL_BASE + path + ".ascx"
        LoadUserControl();
    }
```

User control

```
    protected void profileBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Utils.Events.triggerRedirectPage("Login");
    }
```

Event

```
public class Events
{
    public delegate void redirectEvent(string path);
    public static event redirectEvent redirectPage;

    public static void triggerRedirectPage(String path)
    {
        if (Utils.Events.redirectPage != null)
            Utils.Events.redirectPage(path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches that you can follow.

**Approach 1:**

```
public interface IEventProvider
{
  void TriggerEvent();  
}

public class YourPage: Page, IEventProvider
{
   // Other page methods

   public void TriggerEvent()
   {
     // Your Implementation
   }
}

public class YourUserControl : WebUserControl
{
    protected void profileBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IEventProvider eventProvider = this.Page as IEventProvider;
        if(eventProvider != null)
           eventProvider.TriggerEvent();
    }
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
public interface IEventProvider
{
    // This does not have to be a boolean. You can use a string / enum / anything that suits your implementation
    bool Trigger {get; set;}
}

public class YourPage: Page, IEventProvider
{
   // Other page methods

   protected override void OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
   {
     // This will be raised when all the events have fired for all the controls in the page. 
     if(this.Trigger)
        TriggerEvent();
   }

   protected void TriggerEvent()
   {
     // Your code here
   }

   public bool Trigger
   {
     get;
     set;
   }
}

public class YourUserControl : WebUserControl
{
    protected void profileBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IEventProvider eventProvider = this.Page as IEventProvider;
        if(eventProvider != null)
           eventProvider.Trigger = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I only half get this. where did CreateChildControls come from? and how would you access either the method or the property from the usercontrol? I was under the impression is can't "see" the page above it.

Comment: Okay I have removed the confusing parts of code. Let me know whether this helps.

Comment: That is understandable now thank you!, Now I have a new issue. That all works up to a point. I have two user controls and a main page. User control 1 is loaded in on the initial load. A button is pressed on it and it is unloaded and usercontrol 2 loads up fine. Then I press a home button which unloads 2 and loads 1 back in. However if I press the button on UC1 again; the event doesn't fire the first time, I am stepping through the lines and the button call back is not ran until the button is click a second time :/.

Comment: In which event are you loading the user controls?

Comment: The trigger event method accepts a string and is same internally as `Events_redirectPage(string path)` in my original question

Comment: The reason for the event not firing in the first time is because you add the control to the page late in the request pipeline. Can you move the code to load the user control to "OnInit" or to "CreateChildControls"? If not, then you might have to raise the post back event yourself from the page using IPostbackEventHandler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72229/discussion-between-colobusgem-and-sarathy).